# is it possible to have a multi node kafka cluster, in which all nodes are pointing to the same single instance of zookeeper?

Tags: apache-kafka

is it possible to have a multi node kafka cluster, in which all nodes are pointing to the same single instance of zookeeper?
I have a docker container, which has both, the kafka and zookeeper
I want to set up a second kafka node (on a separate host and without docker), which would point to the same zookeeper.
Are there any special configuration parameters, which I need to set in my server.properties file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is it possible to have a multi node kafka cluster, in which all nodes
>   are pointing to the same single instance of zookeeper?

Of course you can do that, Kafka rely on Zookeeper to store status and config information, but no restriction on the size of Zookeeper cluster.  Less ZK node provide less availability guarantee but no impact to whole cluster functionality.

Just config new Kafka node with unique id and point to same zookeeper node.
**broker.id=*unique-id***
**zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181**

Comment: @Eugene, and also don't forget to assign unique `broker.id` to each kafka broker.

Comment: Sure, Let me add this.